# How to design euclidean lost layer of dlib dnn?

Tags: c++, conv-neural-network, dlib

In the paper "[Accurate Image Super-Resolution Using Very Deep Convolutional Networks](http://cv.snu.ac.kr/research/VDSR/)", they define loss function as encludien distance of `[high resolution image - low resolution image] == [true residual]` and `[network output] == [predict residual]`. The purpose of the loss function is minimize the loss between true residual and predicted residual.

More precisely, the objective is minimize `((r-f(x))^2)/2`
r is the true residual, f(x) is the predict residual.

Following is the implementation of the loss function

```
double compute_loss_value_and_gradient (
        const tensor& input_tensor,
        const_label_iterator truth,
        SUBNET& sub
        ) const
{
    DLIB_CASSERT(input_tensor.num_samples() != 0);

    auto const &output_tensor = sub.get_output();
    tensor& grad = sub.get_gradient_input();
    DLIB_CASSERT(input_tensor.num_samples() == output_tensor.num_samples());
    DLIB_CASSERT(grad.nc() == input_tensor.nc() && grad.nr() == input_tensor.nr());
    DLIB_CASSERT(input_tensor.nr() == output_tensor.nr() &&
                 input_tensor.nc() == output_tensor.nc() &&
                 input_tensor.k() == output_tensor.k());

    double loss = 0;
    output_label_type update_gradient(grad.nr(), grad.nc());
    update_gradient = 0;
    for(long i = 0; i != output_tensor.num_samples(); ++i){
        auto const predict_residual = image_plane(output_tensor, i);
        DLIB_CASSERT(predict_residual.nr() == truth->nr() &&
                     predict_residual.nc() == truth->nc());
        //I set the label(truth) as
        //[high_res_img - low_res_img] == [truth residual_img].
        auto const error_residual = *truth - predict_residual;
        auto const eu_dist = sum(pointwise_multiply(error_residual, error_residual));
        //after derivative, gradient of euclidean distance are
        //input - reference, since output_tensor is a mini batch
        //I sum all of them together
        update_gradient += error_residual;
        loss += eu_dist;
        ++truth;
    }
    //I take the average as the gradient value
    update_gradient /= output_tensor.num_samples();
    auto *grad_ptr = grad.host_write_only();
    std::copy(&update_gradient(0), &update_gradient(0) + update_gradient.size(),
              grad_ptr);

    return loss / 2.0 / output_tensor.num_samples();
}
```

However this loss function do not work well(loss stuck around 8.88~8.9 and do not seem to converge), I guess it is because gradient update has bug.

If you need whole source codes, I put it at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GyRTPLjy). Network architecture is

```
template<typename SUBNET>
using con_net = relu<bn_con<con<64,3,3,1,1, SUBNET>>>;

using net_00 = loss_euclidean_dist<
relu<bn_con<con<1,3,3,1,1,
repeat<3, con_net,
con_net<
input<matrix<float>>
>>>>>>;
```

The paper implement the network by 20 convolution layers and use gradient clip to avoid the problem of gradient explosion/vanishing, instead I use 5 convolution network for experiment purpose and prefer batch normalization to avoid gradient explosion/vanishing.

params of trainer and optimizer

```
    dnn_trainer<vsdr::net_00, adam> trainer(net, adam(0.0001, 0.9, 0.999));
    trainer.set_learning_rate(0.001);
    trainer.set_min_learning_rate(1e-7);
    trainer.set_mini_batch_size(128);
```

Edit 0: function `to_label` never called when training.

Edit 1: I do not apply sqrt on the distance, because this could simplify the derivative

Edit 2 : Found the problem of euclidean lost, the way I update gradient is wrong.

```
double compute_loss_value_and_gradient (
            const tensor& input_tensor,
            const_label_iterator truth,
            SUBNET& sub
            ) const
    {
        DLIB_CASSERT(input_tensor.num_samples() != 0);

        auto const &output_tensor = sub.get_output();
        tensor& grad = sub.get_gradient_input();
        DLIB_CASSERT(input_tensor.num_samples() == output_tensor.num_samples());
        DLIB_CASSERT(grad.nc() == input_tensor.nc() && grad.nr() == input_tensor.nr());
        DLIB_CASSERT(input_tensor.nr() == output_tensor.nr() &&
                     input_tensor.nc() == output_tensor.nc() &&
                     input_tensor.k() == output_tensor.k());

        double loss = 0;
        for(long i = 0; i != output_tensor.num_samples(); ++i){

            auto const error_residual = image_plane(output_tensor, i) - *truth;
            auto const eu_dist = sum(pointwise_multiply(error_residual, error_residual));
            grad.set_sample(i, error_residual);
            loss += eu_dist;
            ++truth;
        }

        return loss / 2.0 / output_tensor.num_samples() / output_tensor.nc()/ output_tensor.nr();
    }
```

Another problem is the network architecture, it should not add relu on top of the last conv layer.

```
using net_00 = loss_euclidean_dist<
bn_con<con<1,3,3,1,1,
repeat<3, con_net,
con_net<
input<matrix<float>>
>>>>>;
```

Now the training process looks much better, but the predicted residual is bad, psnr of the enlarge even worse than bicubic. I try to remove batch normalization and use very low learning rate(1e-5) to avoid gradient explosion, but this cannot work either.

Comment: I dont see any easy-to-find problems in your code. Only small ideas: how about using sgd solver and dropout layer? also, about loss value 8.88~8.9 - this is sum of separate pixel loss. when you will increase resolution of training images - loss will increase. I recommend you make loss /= (nc * nr * k)

Comment: @Evgeniy Thanks, just saw your comments. I tried sgd, but it could not give good result either. Haven't given dropout a try yet, because usually dropout only apply on fc layer + batch normalization do not use with dropout. I think making loss as loss /= (nc * nr * k) is a good idea